# Laravel validation with required parameter without using array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, eloquent

Here my code :

```
$validated = request()->validate([
        'q' => 'required|string',
    ]);
```

I want the same without using an array.
I tried this :

```
$validated = request()->validate('q', 'required|string');
```

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$request->has()` to check if a parameter has been sent.

```
$request->has('q');
```

Request parameters are all strings by default, but you can do an extra check for `null` by using get with a default value.

```
if ($request->get('q', null) !== null) {
    // $q is set!
}
```

Comment: In my situation is : $validated->has('q') ?

Comment: No, in your situation its `request()->has('q')`.